# How to make button widget of Tkinter get automatically pressed with the change in input at other pins

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspbian, gpio

I am using Tkinter with my Raspberry Pi, I want the button widget to get automatically toggled based on the inputs on my GPIO pins.I have created a button widget and I have GPIO pins 11, 12 as inputs and GPIO pin 7 as output,If both the pins(11, 12) are high then my button must automatically get pressed and my output pin 7 must be HIGH.

what I was able to do is if I press the button after both inputs are HIGH then my output becomes HIGH. But without pressing the button it should Automatically get pressed. I am using Tkinter well. no issues with coding please suggest me a method or a code by which I can do so.

Comment: I think what you need is the invoke method http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm.

Comment: Thanks, Can u please help me with an example how can i use this function

Comment: First this question is off topic here (not specific to the Pi, but more of a Tkinter question) and I will migrate it to our sister site stackoverflow. Second the best way to do this would be to just call the function attached to the button click event.

Comment: Would be great if you provide some code. But in your case it would be just `your_button.invoke()` if your pins are `HIGH`

Comment: When you say "automatically toggled", what do you mean exactly? Buttons have a visual representation, so are you saying you want the button to appear in the pressed down state? Buttons are also tied to functions, so are you saying you want the function associated with a button to be called?

Comment: To be clear i want my button to be pressed without a mouse click or touch.I have made my button to 'SUNKEN' when it is pressed ,so I want my button to be 'SUNKEN' when my GPIO's are high.

Answer (score 0):

To run a function associated with a button you can call the `invoke` method of that button.

```
button = tk.Button(...)
...
if (pin_is_high(11) and pin_is_high(12)):
    button.invoke()
```

(I don't now how you're checking the pins, so `pin_is_high` is just a placeholder for however you're checking the pins)